# What is the meaning for [[install-prefix]?

Tags: mesos

Currently I wish to write a Script for Apache Mesos to start the master/slave (on 2 different node).

I have refer to http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/deploy-scripts/ and it state

> [install-prefix]/var/mesos/deploy/masters

What does [install-prefix] means? & anyone knows what details should I write in the script?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

See the help in the `configure` script that you run before building Mesos:

> Installation directories:
>
> --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
>                             [/usr/local]
>
> --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
>                             [PREFIX]
>
> By default, `make install` will install all the files in
>   `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib` etc.  You can specify
>   an installation prefix other than `/usr/local` using `--prefix`,
>   for instance `--prefix=$HOME`.

Comment: By the way, I would like to ask another question. It is we have to install Mesos on another node to run mesos-slave? Or we can just run mesos-slave on anywhere?

Comment: You can run the slave on other nodes, or even run multiple slaves from the same executable on the same node, but with different ports/resources. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597521/can-mesos-master-and-slave-nodes-be-deployed-on-the-same-machines/26647706#26647706

Comment: Okay noted, do you know to run mesos master/slave as a service instead? Because everywhere is just the theory details. No examples or details to show actually how does it work from the beginning and etc.

Comment: The following blog has a good description of Mesos as a service: http://frankhinek.com/setup-mesos-multi-node-cluster-on-ubuntu/ TL;DR: install the Mesos packages from Mesosphere, then you can run, for example, `sudo service mesos-master start`