# VM architecture for running HA Mesos Cluster

Tags: apache-zookeeper, high-availability, mesos

I'm reading the [Mesos Architecture docs](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/architecture/) which, ironically, don't actually specify which components are supposed to run on which VMs/physicals.

It looks like, to run Mesos in HA, you need several categories of components:

1. Mesos Masters
2. ZooKeeper instances (quorum)
3. Hadoop clusters (job nodes? name nodes?)

But there's never any mention of how many you need of each type.

So I ask: **How many VMs/physicals do you need to run Mesos with HA, and what components should be deployed to each?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the [HA docs](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/high-availability/)? To run Mesos in HA, you'll need the Mesos Masters and ZooKeeper. Any Hadoop-related configurations are out of scope for Mesos HA itself.

To have a HA setup, you'll need a uneven number of nodes for the Masters and ZooKeeper (because of quorum mechanism). In our case, we're running 3 Master and 3 ZooKeeper nodes on 3 machines (one Master and one ZooKeeper instance per machine), and a number of Mesos Slaves/Agents on different machines.

Theoretically, the Slaves/Agents can run on the same machines as the Masters/ZooKeepers as well. I guess this is a matter of preferences and availability of machines, and your SLA needs.

If you want to run a large-scale production setup, it will probably make a lot of sense to even separate the Master and ZooKeeper instances.

Further references:

- http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/operational-guide/
- http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/ (see "Master Options")
- [Can Mesos 'master' and 'slave' nodes be deployed on the same machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597521/can-mesos-master-and-slave-nodes-be-deployed-on-the-same-machines)